# Identifying a rhododendron variety

Tags: identification, rhododendrons

I have a rhododendron that's been living in a pot for a couple of years. Beyond the general advice I've found regarding care for it, I'd like to determine what specific variety it is, as there may be more specific requirements that I can adhere to so as to best maintain it.

It's currently (mid-May) flowering, in the UK on the same latitude as London in a reasonably sheltered South-West facing garden. Some pictures of the flowers and density of flowers are at the end of the post.

Three points that may help with identifying the specific variety:

- The flowers are a more vibrant yellow "in person"; unfortunately the camera doesn't really do the colour justice
- The flowers start off (sort of!) red, as can be seen at the bottom of the photo that shows the flowers in close-up
- It's evergreen
- It also flowered (some 5 to 10 flowers) again this year in early September 2019

I've looked at the list of cultivars on the RHS website ([link](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=529)) but none of the listed mid-season flowering ones seem to be good matches

[image: Flowers on the rhododendron]

[image: The full plant, showing flower density]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to identify Rhododendrons even in person, due to the shear abundance of breeding that continues to happen.   There is also the problems with the colour your camera caputures is based on the quality of the camera and the lighting at that moments.  Then there is my computer screen, the setting and the quality of it might show different colour than what you camera took.  Then there are the variations in varieties based on soil, temps, etc.. Some soil will cause this plant to be yellower than others or bring out the red buds more.

All rhodos have the ability of reblooming in fall, especially if they were under stress during the summer, like a particularly dry summer.

If I were to guess, I would guess you have Nancy Evans, the most popular of the yellow rhododendrons.  Nancy Evan starts off with red buds, that usually, but not always, open a dark yellow that fades to a buttery yellow, but always having traces of the red through out.

[Nancy Evans RHS](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/48221/i-Rhododendron-i-Nancy-Evans/Details)

The care is going to be the same as all rhodos.